# emacs disregard highlighting after keyword

Tags: emacs, colors, highlight

I'm working on a pamcrash-mode.el for emacs to simplify my life. Highlighting single phrases works fine by using

```lisp
(defvar pamcrash-keywords_red
  '("NAME" "SENSOR" "DATACHECK" "UNIT" "TITLE" "TIME" "INCLU"))

(defvar pamcrash-docu
  '("Autor" "Datum" "Basis" "VARIANTE" "BASISVAR." "DATUM" 
    "BEARBEITER" "BESCHREIBUNG" "HISTORY" "VERSION" "CAEBENCH" ))

(defvar pamcrash-font-lock-defaults
  `((
    ( ,(regexp-opt pamcrash-keywords_red 'words) . font-lock-warning-face)
    ( ,(regexp-opt pamcrash-docu 'words) . font-lock-comment-face)
    )))

(define-derived-mode pamcrash-mode fundamental-mode "PAM-Crash mode"
  (setq font-lock-defaults pamcrash-font-lock-defaults) )

(provide 'pamcrash-mode)
```

However some lines in Pam-Crash files reads as follows:

```
    NAME This is a string including the keyword SENSOR
    NAME This is a string including the keyword Autor
```

SENSOR/Autor are usually keywords and has to be highlighted, but here there are part of a string and should not. How can I deactivate the color-contrasting of keywords after NAME?

Comment: In general, strings should be highlighted before keywords, so that keyword-highlighting pass would skip string contents. Is there a generic syntax rule that could be used to match strings?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specifically deactivating `SENSOR` / `Autor` highlighting after the `NAME` keyword, I think that you should restrict the relevant regular expressions to match only when the keywords are in the correct position or context.

For example, if the `NAME` and `SENSOR` keywords should appear at the beginning of a line, enforce this constraint in the regular expressions. You could for example build the matching regexes like this:

```lisp
(defvar pamcrash-font-lock-defaults
  `((
    (,(concat "^[[:space:]]*" (regexp-opt pamcrash-keywords_red 'words)) . font-lock-warning-face)
    (,(concat "^[[:space:]]*" (regexp-opt pamcrash-docu 'words)) . font-lock-comment-face)
    )))
```

Comment: Hi Francesco, 

thanks for your fast reply and sorry for my delay.

Unfortunately, your hint doesn't work. Either nothing happend (concat ... is below the line ( ,(regexp-opt pamcrash-keywords_red 'words) . font-lock-warning-face) or nothing happend.

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer how `(concat "^[[:space:]]*")` should be integrated in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following rule *before* your rules:

```
("\\<NAME\\> *\\(.*\\)" 1 font-lock-string-face)
```

This will color everything after the `NAME` keyword using the face for *string*.

Also, modify your rules to read:

```
( ,(regexp-opt pamcrash-keywords_red 'words) 0 font-lock-warning-face keep)
( ,(regexp-opt pamcrash-docu 'words) 0 font-lock-comment-face keep)
```

Where `keep` indicates that if there already is a color (read: the string color), then this should not alter it.

Note: This should not be confused with the syntactic coloring font-lock performs based on information found in the syntax table.

Answer (score -1):

If you swicht to ViM, there is a complete pamcrash syntax available